# Ghostscript check, sends e-mail if one occurs

Tags: ruby, email, ssh, status-monitoring

I've created a program that will search our work server where Ghostscripts occur. How it accomplishes this is by first `ssh`ing to the server specified, running a bash command to search the server for Ghostscripts caused by our guy that uses them, most frequently. If it finds one, it e-mails somebody on my team. It will also e-mail if it doesn't find one.

I'm curious to know if there are other ways I can do this specific task. Better syntax, etc..

```
#!/local/usr/bin/ruby

require 'rubygems'
require '<mailgem>'
require 'etc'
require 'net/ssh'

class GhostScript

  attr_accessor :host, :usr, :pass

  def initialize(host, usr, pass)
    @host = host
    @usr  = usr
    @pass = pass
  end

  def script_search
    ssh = Net::SSH.start(host, usr, :password => pass)
    res = ssh.exec!('ps -u <user>|grep gs')
    if res == nil
      MailGem::Mail.new do |m|
        m.to      = '<email-address>'
        m.subject = 'GhostScript not found'
        m.body    = "GS not found on server: #{host}"
      end.send
      else
      alert(res)
    end
  end

  def alert(res)
    MailGem::Mail.new do |m|
      m.to      = '<email-address>'
      m.subject = 'GhostScript found'
      m.body    = "GS script found on server: #{host}",
                  "Results of search: #{res}"
    end.send
  end
end

check = GhostScript.new('<server>', Etc.getlogin, nil)
check.script_search
```

Comment: Isn't `res` always a (possibly empty) string?

Comment: @Spike I've had this conversation with someone once before, it runs a bash command and either returns `nil`, an empty string, or the command. For some reason `nil` always works for me, so I just use it because it's easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks pretty good, just some minor details:

- `if res == nil` -> `if !res`
- DRY the sending of the email by creating a new method: `send_email(to, subject, body)`
- Subjective: I'd not include a blank lines when there is a change of indentation level (between `class` and `attr_accesor`)

Comment: I just think the space makes it look a little bit neater. I'm confused as to what this would do exactly `!res`, does it do the same thing as the `== nil` just shorter? Also, the method is a good idea, I'll work that in somehow.

Comment: 1) The rationale for not adding this blank line is consistency: why do you add there and not between `def initialize(host, usr, pass)` and `@host = host`, for exemple?  2) `if !res` translates to `if res == nil || res == false`, which is not exactly what you had, but probably it works all the same. It's more idiomatic (because it's more declarative).